# Inserting data from Windows form results in duplication into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

Okay so I'm writing a windows form application that sends and receives data from and to a database. But when I'm inserting into the database I end up getting two rows of the same data. Here is my C# code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tell", txtTel.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", txtCell.Text);
cmd.CommandText = "InsertPerson";
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
con.Close();
```

Could someone please help me solve where this problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the same command twice...

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I assume your stored procedure is returning data after it performs the INSERT.  In that case, you only need the ExecuteReader.

Comment: Did not notice that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the query twice:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         // first time executing
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  // second time executing
```